# What is the gradient and directional vector of a scalar field $f(r)=\cos(x) + 3\sin(y)+4\cos(z)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis, scalar-fields

For a scalar field $f(r)=\cos(x) + 3\sin(y)+4\cos(z)$ is the gradient just $-\sin(x) +3\cos(y)-4\sin(z)$?

or is it $(-\sin(x),3\cos(y),-4\sin(z))$?

In terms the directional vector of f in the direction of â does the directional vector need to be <= sqr(26)?

Comment: Hint: gradient is a **vector**. It has the same number of dimensions as the field on which you are taking the gradient.

Comment: The gradient of a scalar field is a vector vector field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient of a scalar field is a vector field, whose magnitude is the rate of change and which points in the direction of the greatest rate of increase of the scalar field. Thus for the three dimensional scalar field $\phi(x,y,z)=\cos(x) + 3\sin(y)+4\cos(z)$, we have $$\text{grad}\phi(x,y,z)=\nabla\phi(x,y,z)$$
$$=\big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\big)\phi(x,y,z)$$
$$=(-\sin(x),3\cos(y),-4\sin(z)).$$